# How do I assign a distinct value to each row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I have a table like this:

```
Table 1
a    b    c

1    2    5
2    1    6
5    2    2
4    8    4
```

And it goes on for thousands of rows. How do I assign each row a distinct integer (ideally starting with 1 and increasing by 1 for every row)?

Comment: You don't have any `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns there?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is probably to add an auto-incrementing primary key (assuming you don't have a primary key set):

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a query, you would just use a variable:

```
select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
from table1 t1 cross join
     (select @rn := 0) vars;
```

I would recommend using `order by` with an appropriate column to ensure the values are in the order you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should create a new column called 'id' and automatically assign integers in whatever order it retrieves the records in currently.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` ADD COLUMN `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```